# Does wordpress.com support 3rd party themes?

Tags: wordpress, theme

I just purchased WordPress Value Bundle worth $99 from WordPress and now I am having a hard time customizing my blog's theme.

I am unable to install 3rd party themes. Can I just customize fonts, background images, etc.? What good is that? I am super confused and lost.

Why cant I use a customized theme with all the jQuery stuff? Did I just lose $99?

I wanted to use [this theme](http://wpcorner.com/orsted-theme/) for my blog. What do I do now? What can be done?

Answer (score 5):

If your blog is hosted on wordpress.com [you can't actually use 3rd party themes](http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/adding-new-themes/).

The [custom design](http://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/) option allows you to modify the css and the font's but nothing else - especially not the html.

If you need this functionality i'd recommend you get a refund, export your wordpress.com content, move to a self hosted solution and use the [wordpress import plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-importer/) to reassemble your site.

Comment: ohh..can i get a refund?? that would be awesome but can I really??

Comment: I'm certain if you email support they will refund your money, as it isn't that clear that you can't use third party themes.

Comment: http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/

Answer (score 2):

When you use Wordpress.com, even with [premium](http://en.wordpress.com/products/) features, all you can do is pick one of their themes and customise the css.

I would ask for your money back and try and find hosting which supports PHP. Then you can install wordpress and any theme you want.